How to check empty line between license header and package name in Checkstyle
Could anyone say how to check the presence of empty line between license header and package name, if it is possible. I mean:
/*
 * My license
 */
            <-- I need an empty line here and I want checkstyle to check it
package com.foo;


It looks like RegexpHeader should do the trick; see https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/checks/header/regexpheader.html#RegexpHeader.  Note that the first example (line 7) shows a case where a empty line is mandated after the header.

You can use the EmptyLineSeparator check including the PACKAGE_DEF in the tokens parameter for your use case.
A simple example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module
  PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
            <property name="tokens" value="PACKAGE_DEF"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>


Sorry for the late response and thank you for your solution. This is what I was looking for.
